# javascript getDay() showing wrong day for older dates

Tags: javascript, date

I would like to find day for older dates(from year 1000),When I try to find day for
**"30th sep 1494"** using javascript **getDay()** function I am getting Sunday instead of Tuesday,code I tried is

```
var date=new Date(1494,08,30)
date.getDay()
```

I am getting 0 as return value(Which refer SUNDAY)

Note:
I am aware that month start from 0 and 0-is SUNDAY and 6-SATURDAY

(Link for console result:[console screen shot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jm8fmdbq0ypzigr/snap.PNG?dl=0) )

Please give me any alternative way to find day for given date using javascript

Comment: How have you verified that 30 Sep 1494 was Tuesday?

Comment: http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=1494&country=35 and many other source

Comment: And now check here: http://www.worldtimeserver.com/calendar.aspx?y=1494 It says it was Sunday.

Comment: Hmmm, PHP says it was a monday. One of these three is wrong.

Comment: @santoo The info says that timeanddate.com uses Julian Calender, which has an error of one day every 128th year.

Comment: @salman monday is correct if it is based on UTC time

Comment: @Teemu how Julian date could be in Gregorian format?

Comment: I've no idea, that's just what they state below the calendar.

Comment: I guess both Sunday and Tuesday are correct - in a way. Sunday is calculated by [Gregorian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) (JS Date is based on 1st Jan 1970 00:00 (Gregorian date)). Anyway, in 1494 [Julian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar) was in use, and the actual day at that date was really Tuesday. Notice, that Gregorian/Julian is switched depeneding the year and country. at the site.

Answer (score -1):

Try momen JS ( http://momentjs.com/ )

You can get it like this :

```
moment(1494-08-30,"YYYY-MM-DD").format('dddd');
```

and will return "Tuesday"

example : http://jsfiddle.net/prasetiady/t69w219a/

Comment: (a) The example code is incorrect (b) moment.js uses JavaScript date so once you fix your code it will return Sunday.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t69w219a/1/ Output: Sunday..... Salman is right, it is based on JavaScript only so will return same result as JS does.

Comment: i miss the date "30th sep 1494" and just see new Date(1494,08,30), and You right Salman 1494-09-30 will return Suday